# Why save init_task struct address to sp_el0 in arm64 boot code __primary_switched?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, boot, arm64

This is an assembly code from linux arm64 (arch/arm64/kernel/head.S).(kernel source 5.4.21)

```
__primary_switched:
    adrp    x4, init_thread_union   -- line 1
    add sp, x4, #THREAD_SIZE        -- line 2
    adr_l   x5, init_task           -- line 3
    msr sp_el0, x5          // Save thread_info   -- line 4
    adr_l   x8, vectors         // load VBAR_EL1 with virtual  -- line5
    msr vbar_el1, x8            // vector table address  -- line 6
    isb                    -- line7
    
    stp xzr, x30, [sp, #-16]!            -- line8
    mov x29, sp                   -- line9
    
    str_l   x21, __fdt_pointer, x5      // Save FDT pointer   -- line10
```

I'll try to explain it and someone please give me light and correct me if I'm wrong.

- line 1 : x4 = (page address of init_thread_union). I found init_thread_union is a variable in the kernel linkerscript.(arch/arm64/kernel/vmlinux.lds). this vmlinux.lds is genearted from vmlinux.lds.S during kernel building.
- line 2 : sp = (x4 + #THREAD_SIZE). looks like setting the stack pointer for this thread. (and looks like this thread is using init_thread_union memory region) (to use 4K bytes from location of init_thread_union as stack for this thread)
- line 3 : x5 = (address of init_task struct), I found init_task is a task_struct for init task.(in init/init_task.c). so this struct contains thread info.
- line 4 : sp_el0 = x5.  why set the stack pointer of exception level 0 with the thread_info? and is this sp_el0 different from the sp in line 2? (I guess we are now in el 1, so sp in line 2 means sp_el1). and x5 is later used in line 10.

I can't understand exactly what this code is doing. especially line 4. What is this code doing?

Comment: Very similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051120/understanding-arm64-assembly-adr-l-ldr-l-str-l-in-a-linux-kernel-code), but I've seen that you narrowed it down!  You could have also simply edited your previous question instead.

Comment: @fuz I had too many questions to contain in one question. so I was going to split it to two or three questions. I didn't know my previous question is still there (I'll remove it and use for next question.)

Comment: Good idea probably.  Unfortunately I am not able to help you with your question as I'm not experienced enough.

Comment: `init_thread_union` is of type `thread_union` which [can be used for a thread's stack](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.21/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1636), apparently. So the first two lines are setting a per-thread unique stack. Saving `init_task` on the EL0 stack is probably done so that EL0 code will know where to find it (I assume the whole routine is called at EL1).

Comment: @MargaretBloom yes, having read your comment, it seems so. so it seems init_thread_union is used as current threads stack, optionally keeping task_struct or thread_info at the lowest address (stack grows down). By the way, I couldn't find this init_thread_union being declared in the kernel source, maybe generated by script..? thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, crash course on stack management on arm64:

At EL1 you have two stack pointer registers that you can access with `mrs`/`msr`: `sp_el1` and `sp_el0`. You also have a register just called `sp` that you can access in most other instructions like `add`, `str`, etc. And then there's another system register called `spsel`, which consists of a single bit that controls whether `sp` is an alias of `sp_el1` or `sp_el0`. To illustrate:

```
movz x1, 0x1000
movz x2, 0x2000
msr sp_el0, x1
msr sp_el1, x2
msr spsel, 0
add x3, sp, 0x10
msr spsel, 1
add x4, sp, 0x20
// AT this point, x3 == 0x1010 and x4 == 0x2020
```

In addition, when you're running at EL1 and you `eret` to EL0, the stack pointer will always be `sp_el0`. But the reason for all of this is that when you take an exception to EL1 again, your stack pointer is *always* switched to `sp_el1`. This is done because every single general-purpose register holds userspace values at that point, and you need a way to save them away without clobbering any of them (or storing to userland memory).
So what kernels usually do is set up an exception stack in `sp_el1` onto which registers can be spilled when taking an exception. When taking an exception from EL1 to EL1 (e.g. an IRQ), then it *should* usually be safe to store the stack pointer that was in use before the exception was taken, so it is possible to run the kernel itself entirely on `sp_el1`.
Most operating systems don't do this, however, and instead add another stack pointer, a "normal kernel stack" if you will. Then the exception flow will look something like this:

1. Take an exception to EL1, the hardware implicitly switches to `sp_el1` and disables interrupts.
2. Spill all general-purpose registers to the exception stack.
3. Replace the value in `sp_el0` with the address of the "normal kernel stack" pointer.
4. Switch to `spsel, 0` and enable interrupts.

Because exception vectors are different depending on whether you came from a context running on `sp_el0` or `sp_el1`, this allows you to confine "expected exceptions" to `sp_el0`, and if you ever take an exception while running on `sp_el1`, you assume you faulted in a critical section and panic.

Now for the code you've shown: all it does in the first four instructions is set up the exception and "normal" stack pointers. It seems to be running with `spsel, 1`.

Also note that `str_l` isn't an actual instruction, but a Linux-specific macro:

```
/*
 * @src: source register (32 or 64 bit wide)
 * @sym: name of the symbol
 * @tmp: mandatory 64-bit scratch register to calculate the address
 *       while <src> needs to be preserved.
 */
.macro  str_l, src, sym, tmp
adrp    \tmp, \sym
str \src, [\tmp, :lo12:\sym]
.endm
```

So the code it would generate is:

```
adrp x5, __fdt_pointer
str x21, [x5, :lo12:__fdt_pointer]
```

Which, as you can see, doesn't use the old value of `x5`.

Comment: ok, after reading your answer, I am still a little confused. first some thoughts. Every process and every thread(in a process) has its own stack. and for example, EL0 can be used for user application and EL1 can be used for OS. So when there so many stacks, you mean there are only sp_el0 and sp_el1 covering all this stacks, right? I guess so. And when there is a function call, the stack frame is decremented and the stack pointer starts from the top of the stack frame(stack grows down). Inside the stack are saved function call parameters, automatic variables, (maybe return values too?).

Comment: With all this in mind, now I understand sp is just an alias for sp_el0, or sp_el1.(I guessed it).  A question for clarification: when an exception happens during EL0, are the registers spilled to sp_el0 stack or sp_el1 stack?(I guess sp_el1 stack..) , another question : there is no stack pointer specially used for exception handling, am I not right?(for arm64)

Comment: fwiw the Linux kernel presently (~5.0 and later) seems to run the kernel exclusively on sp_el1 and does not swap back to using sp_el0 as far as I was able to locate in sources. It now explicitly _does not handle_ exceptions on the thread stack (e.g. sp_el0) and directs exceptions/interrupts to a routine that immediately panics the kernel. see `kernel/entry.S` and `kernel/entry-common.S` in the arm64 subtree.

Answer (score 1):

In the EL0 mode you can only use sp_el0 as a stack pointer, but In the EL1, you could select which one is the stack pointer between sp_el1 and sp_el0 using lsb(least significat bit) in the PSTATE Register. In Current Linux, this value is one. so sp_el1 is used as sp in the EL1 mode(kernel Mode).
and sp_el0 is used as a pointer to current task's task_struct for fast context switching. for this, sp_el0 is set to the init task as the "msr sp_el0 x5". and every time context switch occurs. there is this kind of code which set sp_el0 to current task_struct.

there is another case when entering into EL1 mode from EL0 using svc instruction or interrupt. in that case, sp_el0 is set to the current task's task_struct using __entry_task(task_struct) because sp_el0 is used as stack pointer in the EL0 mode, but in the EL1, sp_el0 is used for another purpose which is described above.

Answer (score 0):

It is a reciprocation of where init_thread_union is located in the kernel source(v5.10).

Open the arch/arm64/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S file to find RW_DATA.

```
. = ALIGN(SEGMENT_ALIGN);
__initdata_end = .;
__init_end = .;

_data = .;
_sdata = .;
RW_DATA(L1_CACHE_BYTES, PAGE_SIZE, THREAD_ALIGN)
```

Tracking RW_DATA shows the following definitions.

```
#define RW_DATA(cacheline, pagealigned, inittask)           \
    . = ALIGN(PAGE_SIZE);                       \
    .data : AT(ADDR(.data) - LOAD_OFFSET) {             \
        INIT_TASK_DATA(inittask)                \
        NOSAVE_DATA                     \
        PAGE_ALIGNED_DATA(pagealigned)              \
        CACHELINE_ALIGNED_DATA(cacheline)           \
        READ_MOSTLY_DATA(cacheline)             \
        DATA_DATA                       \
        CONSTRUCTORS                        \
    }                               \
    BUG_TABLE                           \
```

Here, we track INIT_TASK_DATA once again.

```
#define INIT_TASK_DATA(align)                       \
    . = ALIGN(align);                       \
    __start_init_task = .;                      \
    init_thread_union = .;                      \
    init_stack = .;                         \
    KEEP(*(.data..init_task))                   \
    KEEP(*(.data..init_thread_info))                \
    . = __start_init_task + THREAD_SIZE;                \
    __end_init_task = .;
```

we can see that it is located in vmlinux.lds.S -> RW_DATA -> INIT_TASK_DATA -> init_thread_union.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.