# When and why we choose SP_EL0 as stack pointer?

Tags: arm, arm64, armv8

There is a field named "SpSel" in PSTATE of AArch64. And it is use to select SP between SP_EL0 or SP_ELn in EL1(or higher).
So I want to ask "Under what circumstances do we need to choose SP_EL0 as stack pointer".

In Programmer's Guide, it has sentences as following:

> However, the software can switch to use SP_EL0 inside the handler. When you use this mechanism, it facilitates access to the values from the thread in the
> handler.

But I can't understand it. Please help me about that.
Thanks.

Comment: "software can switch to use SP_EL0 inside the handler" means that you in kernel space (or higher EL) right now. Handler might be system call handler and might want to fetch parameters passed over stack when parameters do not feet in registers. Might be used in interrupt handlers depending on implementation, for example switch back to user stack while handling interrupt would keep kernel stack safe if interrupt handler fails while processing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why save init\_task struct address to sp\_el0 in arm64 boot code \_\_primary\_switched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059491/why-save-init-task-struct-address-to-sp-el0-in-arm64-boot-code-primary-switche)

Comment: Yes, thank you two. I think I almost understand the theroy. And can you recommend some open-source os using this method? I can't find it in Linux 4.12.